# socket.io custom error not showing correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, socket.io

I have socket io setup with a middleware. If a criteria is met, it sends an error in the `next` function.

When the client receives it, it comes out like this:

> Error: No params given

How can I make it not show "Error:", so it shows this "No params given"

```
io.use(async function (socket, next) {
        const data = socket.handshake.query;
        if (!data) next(new Error('No params given'));
    });
```

Comment: What version of socket.io? How are you using the error on the client? An errors `toString()` method will generate the `Error: No params given` string

Comment: @Matt im using v: 2.3.0